# Unresolved reference to 'memory'

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm trying to add a mif file in the testbench, and I am getting errors.

I am using the modelsim simulator, and I am getting error as:

```
UNRESOLVED REFERENCE TO MEMEORY
 Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'dout'.
#  Error loading design
```

---

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
    
    module ESC_tb;
    
    // Internal TB Signal Definition 
    reg clock; 
    reg reset;
     wire [4:0] pc_out; 
     wire [7:0] acc_out; 
     wire [7:0] mdr_out; 
     // DUT Instantiation 
     ESC instESC(.clock (clock), 
                    .reset (reset),
                    .pc_out (pc_out),
                    .acc_out(acc_out), 
                    .mdr_out(mdr_out)
                    ); 
    // Initialize block for Clock and Reset 
    initial 
    begin : RESET 
    
        reset = 0; 
        #7 reset = 1; 
        #18 reset = 0; 
    
    end 
    
    initial 
    begin : CLOCK 
        clock = 1; 
        #5 clock = 0; 
        forever #(5) clock = ~clock; 
    end
    
    // Loading Program and Data Memory 
    initial 
    begin : MEMLOAD 
        #5; 
 // GETTING ERROR AT THIS POINT
      $readmemh("program.mif", memory); 
 /*66*/ 

$display("Loaded Memory with program.mif file"); 
    end 
    
    initial 
    begin : DUMP_FINISH 
        $dumpvars; 
        #1000 
        $finish(2); 
    end 
    endmodule
```

MEMORY.FILE

```
module memory (clock, addr, din, we, dout,clear);
// Input/Output Declaration
    input clock;
    input [4:0] addr;
    input [7:0] din;
    input we,clear;
    output [7:0] dout;

    // Signal Type Definition
    wire clock;
    wire [4:0] addr;
    wire [7:0] din;
    wire we;
    wire [7:0] dout;// Memory Array Declaration of Size 16x256
    reg [7:0] mem [0:31];
// Memory Write Operation
always @(posedge clock) 
begin
    if(we)
    mem[addr] <= din;
    if(clear)
    mem[addr] <= 0;
end
// Memory Read Operation
assign dout = mem[addr];
// End of Module Declaration
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`memory` is a module, `$readmemh` is looking for an array. You need to give the full path from the test bench to `mem` (within the `memory` module), or call `$readmemh` within the `memory` module.

- From TB: `$readmemh("program.mif", ESC_tb.instESC./*rest of path*/.mem);`
- From `memory` module: `initial $readmemh("program.mif", mem);`